# Sending a int8_t as a uint8_t without changing bit pattern

Tags: c, casting, uart

I am working on a PIC micro controller to send some information over a UART connection in byte chunks. Some of the information I'm sending over is of type int8_t. I want to preserve the bit pattern when sending the information over, but whether or not I explicitly cast, the underlying bit pattern gets changed when the int8_t is a negative value. The library function is declared roughly like this, and accepts a uint8_t to send data, so rewriting that is something that I don't want to do.

For reference, the UART send function is declared like this:

```
void EUSART1_Write(uint8_t txData);
```

How would I go about sending data with type int8_t without changing the bit pattern using the function above? I think that it would be some sort of casting...

Comment: Can you give an example of (negative) numbers and which bit pattern you see?

Comment: you're casting `int8_t` to `uint8_t` and the bits are changing?

Comment: This might be an endian issue.

Comment: implicitly casting `int8_t` to `uint8_t`? Please give example of what you've done and the outcome.

Comment: On most systems casting int8_t to uint8_t doesn't change the bit pattern. Can you show the bit patterns before and after the cast?

Comment: @immibis I'd expect an all compliant systems casting `int8_t` to `uint8_t` to not change the bit pattern.  The width is 8 and `int8_t` uses 2's complement.

Comment: @chux not all systems use 2's complement, also not all systems are properly compliant, also there's a good chance the bit patterns actually are the same and there's an error somewhere else.

Comment: @immibis  As `int8_t` is specified by C to be 2's complement 8-bits, I agree: error somewhere else.

Comment: @smac89 you were right on the endianness of the systems. I had simplified the problem a little bit for the sake of asking a question, but essentially I was sending an int16_t in byte chunks and the entire endianness was messed up because the bytes were out of order, and the bits were reversed -_-

Comment: @immibis by "most systems" you mean "all conforming systems which offer these types"

Answer (score 0):

Make a pointer then cast the pointer, then the original data will not be cast

```
EUSART1_Write(*(uint8_t*)(&signed_data_that_you_want_to_send));
```